# What's the default background colour res which changes based on dark mode? [Android]

Tags: android, material-design, darkmode, android-darkmode

I have a coordinator layout which has a bottom sheet.

By default, my bottom sheet's background is transparent. So I put `color/white` as the background res for the parent layout.

This works fine in light mode, but in dark mode, my text automatically adjusts its colours to white to suit dark mode. But now with the white background of the bottom sheet, I can't see the text.

Typically with dark/light modes, material design tends to handle the switching of colours mostly for you. However, since I have to define a background colour for my bottom sheet, I'm not sure what to define for it so that it switches to white/dark grey depending on dark/light mode.

Is there some system included colour res I can use which will change the background colour for me with material design?

Answer (score 0):

Follow Location:

> res>values>themes>themes.xml(night)

then add  tag inside  tag.

```
<item name="android:colorBackground" tools:targetApi="l">@color/white</item>
```

This will change your background color to white only in dark mode.

You can do the same in light mode.

Note:
Do not add colour in layout resource file.